# Php code giving no results in firefox?

Tags: php

Just started learning Php on my own, and got stuck at the beginning. This is the code I was compiling:

```
<?php
  echo "Hello world!";
  echo 6+2;
?>
```

The problem is that  the Php portion isn't displayed in Firefox. Why? Firefox ver. 7.0.1., I am using NetBeans 7, with cygwin.

Comment: Does it gives any result in other browsers? Please paste page source here. And this obviously doesn't look like browser issue, but a php or server configuration issue.

Comment: Are you sure ..It is working in other browser ?

Comment: Err maybe a stupid question, but did you install a local server as apache?

Comment: in PHP the code is not compiled, its interpreted. Which webserver do you use?

Comment: What are you meaning you can't display the PHP portion ? What do you expect to see. With the above code You have to see "Hello world!8". That must be the result. What are you getting as a result ?

Comment: Are you displaying the page through web server?

Comment: @ Merianos : Yes I know, but I didn't see that. I get only the Php portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you're accessing the file directly like `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/PhpVjezba1/test1.php`

Don't do that, access it via `http://localhost/PhpVjexba1/test1.php`, provided you have a server installed.

Click [Here](http://localhost/PhpVjexba1/test1.php)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you haven't installed php on the server yet. Unlike JavaScript and HTML, php is interpreted at the server, and that requires

1. a webserver (like [apache](http://httpd.apache.org/))
2. a php runtime
3. php to be configured

The [documentation's installation chapter](http://php.net/manual/en/install.php) explains how to install php. There are also third-party distributions like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) that try to simplify the installation process.

Answer (score 1):

In the comment you have the problem. You cannot access the file directly.

Start the webserver and run the file "http://localhost/file.php" then the file should work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a stupid question, but are you running PHP from web server or actually trying to run the file directly in browser?

Comment: Why -1 for only some responses that are questions, whilst others which are also questions are untouched? If you are going to excercise a decision on this, please make it uniform.

Comment: I am running the file directly I think. file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/PhpVjezba1/test1.php

Comment: And dont downvote because you wrote the same as a comment, as opposed to an answer, dont forget while you are writing answers you cant see any other updates others are adding...

Comment: Check out http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17447/answer-or-comment-whats-the-etiquette

Comment: @ergo : Sorry I didn't downvote, I am quite new at this so I don't know what that is...

Comment: @nebbs thats fine :) have you had any solution to your issue?

Comment: @ ergo - Is you now doing down vote in all my answer ? have to pay for it !!

Comment: @Rikesh, I am well aware, however sometimes answers can be found through questioning. Still, you're entitled to your opinion, I can respect that

Comment: @ergo - Agree answer can be found through questioning ..But point is where to question in answer or in comments ? Obviously you have to ask a basic and per-requistic question always in comments !!

Comment: @Rikesh Shah This was a question, but it was implying an answer "You're probably not running it via web server" and pointing to a solution. I'm all for clean and proper use of SO, but everything in moderation, including the moderation.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is never displayed in any web browser, it is executed on a web server, and is used (somewhat) to produce html that is displayed to you're web browser.

Do you have a local browser such as wamp?

Comment: yes, I have xampp installed, and both Apache and Mysql are running. Html is diplayed ok, but I was expecting to see "Hello world" in the browser too..?

Comment: check out the html source, perhaps it's simply hidden by firefox because it's not a valid html page

Comment: @Nebbs: And how do you access your php file? http://localhost/test.php should be the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Does the output display in other browsers?

Does your page have the .php extension and is your server set to handle php?